# Programmatically toggle ability to rotate orientation

Tags: objective-c

I am making an app that allows you to free draw ("annotate") over a background image of a music sheet. My app allows me to toggle the drawing to hide/unhide. When I rotate the orientation to landscape, the drawing and the background image do not align in the way that they did for portrait mode, so I would like to prevent orientation change when the drawing is not hidden and re-allow it if the drawing is hidden.

Is this possible? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your view controller do this:

```
-(UIInterfaceOrientationMask)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    if ( drawingView.hidden )
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
    else
        return [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
}
```

Comment: That's a really elegant solution! Thank you.